# Assistance kindly requested with child control on a simple form Visual C#

Tags: c#, forms, controls

Hello everyone I am new to programming and studying C#. I am only a beginner.

I have a form with a `GroupBox` control and within the `GroupBox` there is four `TextBox` controls. There is also a `button`.

I am wanting to test if the `TextBox` are empty by clicking the `button`.

This is my code but it doesn't work correctly.

Please could someone try help me out if they have time ?

```
private bool IsThereDataInControl(Control control) {
  bool isControlEmpty = true;
  foreach(Control c in control.Controls) {
    if (c is TextBox) {
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox) c).Text)) {
        isControlEmpty = false;
      }
    }
    if (c.HasChildren) {
      IsThereDataInControl(c);
    }
  }
  return isControlEmpty;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  bool validate = IsThereDataInControl(this);
  MessageBox.Show(validate.ToString());
}
```

The `messagebox` shows 'True' when there is text in the textbox's.

Comment: Where is `ValidateThereIsData()`? do you want to use `IsThereDataInControl()`?

Comment: oops my mistake. Yes your correct ! I changed the name of the method to make it more intuitive

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (c.HasChildren) {
  IsThereDataInControl(c);
}
```

Into

```
if (c.HasChildren && !IsThereDataInControl(c)) {
    isControlEmpty = false;
}
```

I'm not sure of it works,because I have no acces to a C# compiler atm.

If a control has children in your code, you call `IsThereDataInControl(c);`, but you do nothing with the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to verify all sub-childs, you could do it recursively:

```
  foreach(Control c in control.Controls) {
    if (c is TextBox) {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox) c).Text)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if (c.HasChildren) {
        if (IsThereDataInControl(c)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

The code probably needs to be modified a little bit, I don't have a c# IDE at the moment.